# "this" returns undefined in wepay callback closuer

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, wepay

please i need your help. I am trying to call this to access a variable that i have in my data object in vuejs but **this** returns **undefined**

Here is my code

```
let response = ''
        let self  = this

        response = WePay.credit_card.create({
          "client_id":        118711,
          "user_name":        this.cardDetails.name,
          "email":            this.cardDetails.email,
          "cc_number":        this.cardDetails.number,
          "cvv":              this.cardDetails.cvc,
          "expiration_month": this.cardDetails.month,
          "expiration_year":  this.cardDetails.year,
          "address": {
              "postal_code": this.cardDetails.zipcode
          }
        }, function(data, self) {
          if (data.error) {
            // self.loader = false
            console.log(window)
            this.loader = false
            this.emitErrorNotify({message: data.error_description})
            // handle error response
          } else {
            console.log(data)
              // call your own app's API to save the token inside the data;
              // show a success page
          }
        })
```

Please can anyone help me how it's done? Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define

```
let self  = this
```

up top, 
but inside the `function(data, self)` self is overwritten. Either change one of the variables and use that instead of this.
Or bind `this` to the function so you can use it within:

```
function(data, self) {

}.bind(this)
```

Comment: thanks. it worked using the bind. Thanks again